# IntegrateChangeVariables producing incorrect result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, version-13.1

**Bug introduced in 13.1. and persisting through 14.0**

---

Consider the simple quadratic function:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_]:=x^2;
```

Now let's set up the two identical integrals:

```
integrals={
    IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][f[x],{x,-a,0}],u,u==-x],
    Inactive[Integrate][f[x],{x,-a,0}]
}
```

> $\left\{\int _0^a-u^2du,\int _{-a}^0x^2dx\right\}$

But I was expecting:

> $\left\{\int _0^au^2du,\int _{-a}^0x^2dx\right\}$

Now let's evaluate to get the result:

```
Activate@integrals
```

$\left\{-\frac{a^3}{3},\frac{a^3}{3}\right\}$

Am I using the `IntegrateChangeVariables` incorrectly or there is a bug here?

Comment: Did you report it? Just ran into into this bug in version 13.2.1 [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/IntegrateChangeVariables-bug.nb)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov no can you report it please.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is bug. The integral should be
$$
\int_{a}^{0}-u^{2}du
$$
And not
$$
\int_{0}^{a}-u^{2}du
$$

Proof:

Integrating $\int_{-a}^{0}x^{2}dx$  using change of variable $u=-x$. Hence
$\frac{du}{dx}=-1$ or $dx=-du$. When $x=-a$ then $u=a$. When $x=0$ then $u=0$.
And $x^{2}$ becomes $u^{2}$.

Hence the new integral becomes

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a}^{0}x^{2}dx  & =\int_{a}^{0}u^{2}\left(  -du\right)  \\
& =-\int_{a}^{0}u^{2}du\\
& =-\left[  \frac{u^{3}}{3}\right]  _{a}^{0}\\
& =-\left(  0-\frac{a^{3}}{3}\right)  \\
& =-\left(  -\frac{a^{3}}{3}\right)  \\
& =\frac{a^{3}}{3}
\end{align*}
And not $-\frac{a^{3}}{3}$ as Mathematica says.

Please report to WRI.

This is still experimental. So expect some bugs in it.

[image]

Comment: Using Leticia `Block[Quiet ]` tricks, it seems probably connected to `Inverse functions are being used by Solve` warning