# IntegrateChangeVariables give a wrong result?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 13.1.**

---

```
RegionPlot[x^(1/(x + 1/x)) + y^(1/(y + 1/y)) >= E, {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

We can calculate the area by integral:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[x^(1/(x+1/x))+y^(1/(y+1/y))>=E],{x,0,7},{y,0,7},Method->"LocalAdaptive"]
```

> 13.7593

But I hope to get the exact result, so I try to use the new function `IntegrateChangeVariables`:

```
intexpr = Inactive[Integrate][
   Boole[x^(1/(x + 1/x)) + y^(1/(y + 1/y)) >= E], {x, 0, 7}, {y, 0, 7}];
Activate[IntegrateChangeVariables[intexpr, {r, θ}, 
  "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]]
```

[image]

I note it gives a wrong answer $49$...

Comment: `IntegrateChangeVariables` is still EXPERIMENTAL so it's not too surprising to find something like this. If you remove the `Activate` you'll see how `IntegrateChangeVariables` goes wrong more clearly. Actually there's no example for changing `Integrate` with `Boole` in document of `IntegrateChangeVariables` for now. There does exist example for `ImplicitRegion`, but turning to `ImplicitRegion` only results in unevaluated `IntegrateChangeVariables[…]`.

Comment: A simpler example showing the issue: `intexpr = Inactive[Integrate][Boole[x^2 + y^2 < 1], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]; IntegrateChangeVariables[intexpr, {r, θ}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]`. Definitely a bug. (For this simple case, `ImplicitRegion` helps, though: `reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, y}]; intexpr = Inactive[Integrate][1, {x, y} ∈ reg]; IntegrateChangeVariables[intexpr, {r, θ}, "Cartesian" -> "Polar"]`.

Comment: see also [integratechangevariables-producing-incorrect-result](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270358/integratechangevariables-producing-incorrect-result)

Comment: @xzczd Thank you for your analysis~