# IntegrateChangeVariables doesn't Evaluate at all

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How do I perform the following variable change:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][2x E^-x^2,{x,1,\[Infinity]}],u,u==E^-x^2]
```

Returns unevaluated. Am I missing some condition?

Comment: This change of variables makes the problem harder rather than easier. Just do the original integral `Integrate[2 x E^-x^2, {x, 1, \[Infinity]}]` which evaluates to `1/E`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon, You are right. However, why does the transformation not go?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch - It will evaluate if you include an assumption, e.g., `Assuming[x >= 1, IntegrateChangeVariables[ Inactive[Integrate][2 x E^-x^2, {x, 1, \[Infinity]}], u, u == E^-x^2]]` However, as with @Nasser answer, the sign of the result is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is because you have two branches and it does not know which one to use

```
sol=Solve[u == Exp[-x^2], x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When you pick the right one, then it works

```
sol2 = x /.  Last[sol] // Normal  (*to remove conditional part*)
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][2 x E^-x^2, {x, 1, ∞}], u, x == sol2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

The issue of sign wrong is known and was asked to be reported it before on similar problem with sign.

[IntegrateChangeVariables producing incorrect result](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270358/integratechangevariables-producing-incorrect-result)

(I just noticed it is same OP who asked this question as the above linked to question).

Also note that this function is marked as EXPERIMENTAL so bugs are to be expected? It is better not to use EXPERIMENTAL functions for production code.

Comment: Your result is  a negative number `-1/E`, whereas the original integral is a positive number `1/E`.

Comment: Submit a bug report to Technical Support.

Comment: `Normal` will remove the condition from a `ConditionalExpression`, e.g., `sol2 = x /.  Last[sol] // Normal`

Comment: @BobHanlon good suggestion,. I did not know that. Will update, thanks.