`IntegrateChangeVariables` sometimes doesn't work
For example, the following simple code doesn't work:
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)] , {x, -1, 1}], t, (1 + x)/(
  1 - x) == t]

Instead, if we solve the equation (1 + x)/(1 - x) == t manually, it works:
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)] , {x, -1, 1}], t, 
 x == First@SolveValues[(1 + x)/(1 - x) == t, x]]

This is a very simple example. I am wondering why it doesn't work and how to avoid it.

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279237/1871

Exploring the use of assumptions with your problem, I discovered this unrelated snafu: Assuming[y != 0,  IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][Exp[2 x], x], t, t == 2  x]  ] does not work, but without assumptions, it does!: IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][Exp[2 x], x], t, t == 2  x] -- even though the assumption is irrelevant! I've noticed the "fragility" of IntegrateChangeVariables before. The docs recommend the transformation in the form t == f[x], but they don't say x == g[t] won't work.

Part of the problem is that IntegrateChangeVariables calls AsymptoticSolve with the assumption that $t=0$ at $x=0$ (this is hard-coded). We can try to get around it with an intermediate change of variables:
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}],
 u, (1 + x)/(1 - x) - 1 == u]
(*  Inactive[Integrate][1/2 Sqrt[(2 + u)/(2 - u)], {u, -2, 2}]  *)

BUT the result is wrong. It is the result of substituting x == u/2, which is the solution returned by
AsymptoticSolve[{-1 + (1 + x)/(1 - x) == u}, x -> 0, u -> 0]
(*  {{x -> u/2}}  *)

IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}],
 u, x == u/2]
(*  Inactive[Integrate][1/2 Sqrt[(2 + u)/(2 - u)], {u, -2, 2}]  *)

It seems the decision tree of IntegrateChangeVariables is not robust. For instance, while the OP's fix,
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}],
 t, x == First@SolveValues[(1 + x)/(1 - x) == t, x]]

works, it fails if we switch the sides of the equality,
IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}],
 t, First@SolveValues[(1 + x)/(1 - x) == t, x] == x]

Why use == if the relation is not symmetric within IntegrateChangeVariables?
Summary:
Not all inputs to IntegrateChangeVariables find their way to calling AsymptoticSolve. That the asymptotic approximation is used at all is a surprise, since it is not mentioned in the docs. It seems impossible to me to give advice on how to avoid the problems above. Not enough is known about the internal algorithm and its limitations, and the corner-cases do not seem to lie in remote corners.
The best way for reliable code is to do change variables the old way, before IntegrateChangeVariables, using Mathematica to do the calculus and solve the equations:
IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}], 
  t, (1 + x)/(1 - x) == t] /. 
 HoldPattern[ (* fix a failed IntegrateChangeVariables *)
   IntegrateChangeVariables[
    Inactive[Integrate][f_, {x_, a_, b_}],
    t_, eqn_]] :>
  With[{sub = Solve[eqn, x], invsub = Solve[eqn, t]},
   (* optional checks *)
   If[! ListQ[sub] || 
     Length[sub] > 1 || ! FreeQ[sub, ConditionalExpression],
    Print[
     StringForm["Warning: solving `` for `` yielded ``.", eqn, x, 
      sub]]
    ];
   If[! ListQ[invsub] || 
     Length[invsub] > 1 || ! FreeQ[invsub, ConditionalExpression],
    Print[
     StringForm["Warning: solving `` for `` yielded ``.", eqn, t, 
      invsub]]
    ];
   
   Inactive[Integrate][
    f  Dt[x, t] /. First@sub
    , {t,
     Limit[t /. First[invsub], x -> a, Direction -> Sign[a - b]], 
     Limit[t /. First[invsub], x -> b, Direction -> Sign[b - a]]}]
   ] // Simplify

(*  Inactive[Integrate][(2 Sqrt[t])/(1 + t)^2, {t, 0, ∞}]  *)

This will be as robust as Solve and Limit and assumes a real integral. One could add assumptions or restrictions to Solve to eliminate extraneous solutions and conditional expressions. Normal will blithely remove conditions from a ConditionalExpression, if that seems safe.
One might also try DChange.

OK, well I kept tinkering and made a function, which I thought might as well be shared.
myChangeVariables // ClearAll;
between[a_, x_, b_] := If[a < b, a < x < b, b < x < a];
badsol[sol_] := ! ListQ[sol] || (* not a list *)
   Length[sol] != 1 || (* not a unique solution *)
   ! FreeQ[sol, 
     ConditionalExpression]; (* contains ConditionalExpression *)
myChangeVariables::badsol = "Warning: Solving `` for `` yielded ``.";
myChangeVariables::assum = "Warning: Assuming condition ``.";
myChangeVariables::tautology = 
  "Conditions `` are redundant with other assumptions.";
myChangeVariables[
   Inactive[Integrate][f_, {x_, a_, b_}], 
   t_, eqn_, assum_ : True] :=
  Module[{sub, invsub, conditions, newassum, ta, tb},
   Assuming[between[a, x, b] && assum, (* x between limits etc. *)
    sub = Simplify@Solve[eqn, x, Reals]; 
    invsub = Simplify@Solve[eqn, t, Reals];
    (* checks on Solve *)
    If[badsol[sub], Message[myChangeVariables::badsol, eqn, x, sub]];
    If[badsol[invsub], Message[myChangeVariables::badsol, eqn, t, invsub]];
    (* get new integral limits *)
    Quiet[
     ta = Limit[t /. Last[invsub], x -> a, Direction -> Sign[a - b]];
     tb = Limit[t /. Last[invsub], x -> b, Direction -> Sign[b - a]],
     Limit::alimv];
    Assuming[between[ta, t, tb], (* t between limits *)
     conditions = Join[ (* get condtions from ConditionalExpression *)
       Cases[sub, ConditionalExpression[_, cond_] :> cond, Infinity],
       Cases[invsub, ConditionalExpression[_, cond_] :> cond, 
        Infinity]];
     (* analyze and warn user about conditions/new assumptions *)
     newassum = Simplify@conditions; (* 
     check if True under assumptions so far *)
     With[{tautologies = Pick[conditions, newassum]},
      (* warn user of discarded conditions *)
      If[Length@tautologies > 0, 
       Message[myChangeVariables::tautology, tautologies]];
      newassum = And @@ newassum;
      (* warn user about new assumptions from conditions *)
      If[! TrueQ[newassum], Message[myChangeVariables::assum, newassum]];
      Assuming[newassum,
       
       (* FINALLY, solve the problem *)
       Inactive[Integrate][
         f  Dt[x, t] /. First@sub
         , {t, ta, tb}] // Simplify
       ]]]
    ]];

Examples:
myChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}], t, (1 + x)/(1 - x) == t]


myChangeVariables::badsol: Warning: Solving (1+x)/(1-x)==t for x yielded {{x->(-1+t)/(1+t) if t>0}}.
myChangeVariables::tautology: Conditions {t>0} are redundant with other assumptions.
(*  Inactive[Integrate][(2 Sqrt[t])/(1 + t)^2, {t, 0, ∞}]  *)


myChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][
  Sqrt[(1 + x)/(1 - x)], {x, -1, 1}], t, (1 + x)/(1 - x) == t^2, 
 t <= 0]


(*  Inactive[Integrate][-((4 t^2)/(1 + t^2)^2), {t, 0, -∞}]  *)


